# Magento - Multi-domain & Filters

Tags: php, jquery, magento, filter, filtering

We're looking to build in a filter to our Magento site with drop down choices for the first two options, a selection box for price plus a colour chooser.

Firstly how easy is it to fetch the info for the first two dropdowns from the database so the first box is populated with the first category then the second box populated with the choices for that particular category? (and then change if someone changes the first selection)

Secondly how easy is it to set up a separate filter for each site so it only fetches info for the corresponding store and doesn't show products from other stores?

The filter will only have to show the products when you press a 'find' button so I guess it's a case of building up the search query?

Thoughts and ideas on this would be great, only been working with Magento for a month so still not sure of it's full capabilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part Magento already shows only products relevant to a given store. When you set up the stores (in *System > Store Management*) you have the option of giving it a unique "root category". Creating root categories is easy, in *Catalog > Manage Categories*.

The first part requires some programming work. From your previous questions it looks like you have a good understanding of Javascript so AJAX is not a problem. I don't know how familiar you might be with PHP, listing products will require you create a new module, with it's own controller, that forms a collection from the selected category. Collections make their own queries so you don't need to write a lick of SQL, and they have functions for exporting as JSON or XML so you don't need to write that either. For an experienced programmer it would take almost no time at all.

Comment: Thanks for that, gives me a pointer in the right direction! :)